# How to know when the dumpfile is inserted or any data is updated?

Tags: mysql

For example, I insert the dump filr to my database like this below.

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost mydatabase < mydatabase.dump
```

When it worked there was no message and finished.

I have cron to do this automatically,

so I want to know if it works well or error.

Is there any good way to know when the database data is refreshed?? such as.

```
 mysql -u root -p -h localhost -e "select lastupdatetime from mysql.metadata"
```

Comment: Put the command line into some batch file, after this line put lines which saves the timestamp and error code to some log file.

Comment: Or use `&&` and `||` operators in the command line. Something like `mysql -u root -p -h localhost mydatabase < mydatabase.dump && echo %date% %time% Dump loaded successfully > success.txt || echo %date% %time% Dump loaded with errors > error.txt` (variant for Windows OS)...

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

`\u database_name`

`show tables`

if you find your tables then this is the first hint

`select * from some_table`

if you get a table with data then this is the second hint